# Dealing with IP changes on session/cookie validation

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm trying to figure out another solution than remembering IP for cookie validation.

When a user logs into my site, I generate a sessionCode and store it to a cookie.  On the db, I store the UserId, SessionCode and the IP of the user.  When a user reconnects, it checks for the cookie/sessionCode, and checks it agains the DB with that IP address.  If it matches, it automatically signs them in.

Problem with that solution: 
I do some development in my office and some at home, both almost every day.  everytime I switch ISP (home to work to home etc) My cookie is invalidated.

I'm looking for a solution to help maintain trust of the cookie without IP.  Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm considering the option to assume the user if the code matches, but ask for their password again if the ip is different.

Comment: why not use the built in authentication mechanisms?

Comment: because the default authentication does not include IP validation.  I.e. if the persistant cookie is copied on to another machine, the site would simply trust that you are who you say you are despite that you are now signing in from Hong Kong instead of LA.

Comment: Presently I use the IP with the cookie's session code to help validate the source.  I'm wondering if there are other data points I can use, or improvements on ip validation with fluctuating IP's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't re-invent the wheel:

[How To Implement Forms-Based Authentication in Your ASP.NET Application by Using C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240)

[ASP.NET Forms Authentication Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx)

Comment: the Built in authentication methods, in my opinion, are less secure.  by obtaining a copy of a cookie and placing them on your own machine you could log in as who ever.  At lease by adding IP validation, you are helping to guarantee a user is still on the same machine.  Or at least behind the same router/firewall.  What I am hoping for is some kind of happy medium, other points of identify for the machine for instance.  For instance by storing the ip addresses as an array, and with each new one on the same userid/code it validates your password again, increasing the list count.

Comment: You say less secure, but don't quantify it.  Are you talking theory or do you know how to trick forms auth?  If you can, you should report it to Microsoft.

Comment: Quantification from the first sentence: "by obtaining a copy of a cookie and placing them on your own machine"

Comment: Quote from Wikipedia on Cookies: "attackers can impersonate users’ requests by stealing a full set of victims’ cookies"

Comment: So, you are talking theory my friend.  Yes, it's possible, anything is with a PC, but you can't test or validate this correct?  MAC address is about the only thing unique to a computer/connection but that can be spoofed too.  You are chasing an edge case you can't stop anyway.

Comment: It is actually really easy to test, by just copying the chrome cookie file, or what ever browser's cookies you want to take.  I believe IE has a folder of separated files for every site, but chrome is a simple single file copy.

Comment: But I think the post did speak for itself, that with no one else speaking up, that the common standard is to just use the forms based auth.  I prefer holding on to the IP and just using it as I discussed above, with the added password check on different IPs, keeping track of each 'safe' IP associated with it.  Thanks for your help though, I can see that MS recommends this, but I will keep with the upgraded handling on IPs.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I thought I would just contribute something as I am currently in the process of building out something similar to WarpWars.  Most residential ip addresses are assigned dynamically so the user would have to validate again if the ip changed. An Autonomous System Number( ASN ), however, is supposedly unique to ISPs which may be the better route rather than using the ip address directly.  Using an ASN may solve the issue of your cookie being invalidated.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_(Internet)

This site has a service to get an ASN from the ip and it supports various platforms including .NET:

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/